# Printers & Scanners not showing scan tab for Officejet Pro 8600

Tags: macos, printing, scanning

On my old Macbook Pro with macOS 10.14, Printers & Scanners under System Preferences would show:
[image]

Now on my new M1 Macbook Pro with macOS 12.0.1, I see no "Scan" tab:

[image]

I went to HP's site and installed the driver for this printer, which just gave me "HP Easy Start", but when I run that it just says "getting device information" and spins forever and never does anything.....  Is there another way I can get the scanner for this to show up on OS 12?

Comment: any updates on this? Just ran into the same issue, very disappointing

Comment: my update is I use my 2012 macbook pro to scan.  It is disappointing and down right nonsensical.

Comment: thanks for the update. I very much liked this model, but decided not to buy another HP printer, since they choose to discontinue support in this way.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem.
I was able to install "HP Smart" from here:

https://apps.apple.com/us/app/hp-smart-for-desktop/id1474276998?mt=12

It enables the scan feature.
Good Luck.
Rob

Comment: Are you saying you installed that software and the scan tab showed up in system preferences?  I installed it, and it did not change anything, and if I run the HP Smart app and click "scan" it forces me to create an account which is complete nonsense and I refuse to do that.

Comment: No, it does not make the scan feature appear in preferences. But it does give me the ability to scan. It's not the solution I wanted but I'd rather create create an HP account than have no ability to scan. Like you, I still want to find the real solution that will fix the scanner function in apple preferences.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue with my HP Deskjet 3070A. As suggested I installed HP Smart and I was asked to create an account. I did not want to create an account to simply scan a document.

I found an alternative. You can install HP Easy Scan:
https://apps.apple.com/fr/app/hp-easy-scan/id967004861?mt=12

This program installs the scanner driver your Mac does not have.

At some point, you will be asked if you want to install HP Smart because it is more recent. You seem to do not have alternative but you actually do. Try to quit the installation window then you will be asked to:

1. continue with HP Smart install
2. continue with the current HP Easy Scan installation
3. cancel your exit action

Select the second option.

When asked, you need to install only the "Essential" part.

Once installed you can safely quit the installation without providing personal information such as your zipcode.

At this point you can remove your printer from "Printers and scanners" window then re-add your printer using AirPrint. This is exactly what you did before but now the "Scan" will appear.

Unfortunately your mission does not stop here. When trying to scan something, you probably will receive an alert (as I did) mention you do not have the permission to open the application "HP Scanner 3". This time the HP Support got you covered with this help page: https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/ish_4448469-4448558-16

I hope this message will help you.

Comment: I installed Easy scan, it did not ask me to install hp smart..  And once I run Easy scan, there are no scanners detected-- my hp jet 8600 does not show up at all.  No scan tab in system preferences after installing this.